# What are (meteorolgical) land depressions?

Tags: meteorology, tropical-cyclone

Reading the Wikipedia page for some North Indian Cyclone Seasons I've come across multiple systems called "land depressions". (written as Land [number])

[image: 2018 Season Timeline]

Example (Land 01 2019):
[image: Land01]

I'm not exactly sure what these are. They're depressions, yes, but are they tropical, subtropical, or extratropical? I've read their references but the IMD reports never mentions if they're tropical or not. These Wikipedia articles are usually dedicated to tropical cyclones and the section on related articles even state that these articles are part of the North Indian Tropical Cyclone Seasons, and yet the JTWC does not seem to list these land depressions on their best track.

[image: North Indian Tropical Cyclone Seasons]

Links to the Wiki articles I read:

[2018 North Indian Cyclone Season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_North_Indian_Ocean_cyclone_season)

[2019 North Indian Cyclone Season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_North_Indian_Ocean_cyclone_season#Land_Depression_01)

Comment: They are not extratropical. Those are called Western Disturbances. Land depressions are tropical depressions that form over land. That's it